# Post Data on Wordpress Site By Using PHP Curl

Tags: php, wordpress, post, curl

hi guys i am having a little problem and i am unable to figure it out, I am working on a project we have made application related school management in which we can basically add students,branches,classes make test,show test results,fees management etc.

we also made their website on wordpress my problem is i have a page on my application show results i want to show this page results on their wordpress site by using curl. Basically what i want when user enter his student id and test id and hit search button then show results file which reside on my application showed up. Both application and websites are on different server. Can you guys teach me how can i achieve this. Thanks

Comment: Is the search page receiving $_POST or $_GET parameters?

Answer (score 0):

Post data whit curl:

```
<?php
if(count($_POST) > 0){
    print_r($_POST);
    exit();
}

$c = curl_init();
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POST,true);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,array('param0'=>'value0','param1'=>'value1'));
$output = curl_exec($c);
if($output === false){
    trigger_error('Error curl : '.curl_error($c),E_USER_WARNING);
}
else{
    var_dump($output);
}
curl_close($c);
?>
```

Comment: sorry for noobish question but how can i apply this code in wordpress scenario.Thanks

Comment: Oooh ! you just want to retrieve an RSS feed?  
go on admin panel -> widget -> add widget "Rss" and add url of your feed in widget ;)

Comment: no bro its not rss feed..! when student put his id and test id and hit search button then form will be processed and go to server on which i install my application and find my show results file and shows the result on worspress page!

Comment: try this -> http://www.mariasguides.com/2006/04/16/how-to-create-a-wordpress-rss-feed-page/ and this for search page -> http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Search_Page

Comment: thanks for the link but its not very helping to solve my problem. but anyway thanks i am waiting for more replies!